# Refix all router in one path nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have someone routes like this

```
pages/
--| people/
-----| _id.vue
-----| index.vue
--| order/
-----| _id.vue
-----| index.vue
--| about.vue
--| index.vue
```

It will behave like this

```
/
/people
/people/123
/order
/order/123
/about
```

I want change all this path to

```
/ --> index.vue
/people --> people > index.vue
/123 --> people > _id.vue        !-- this one
/order --> order > index.vue
/123 --> order > _id.vue         !-- and this one are to be changed
/about --> about.vue
```

If have demo is better, thanks all

Comment: Oh wait, you want `/123` and `/123` to lead to either order or people? You know that in a router level, you cannot really make the difference. And it sounds like a bad idea to have 2 different entities accessible via an apex path. Why breaking the convention here? It's totally fine as is. Maybe you could explain us what is your idea behind all of this.

Comment: sorry, i just want know we can sort all route on one path is it possible or not? because if it can do this, the path will be very short and I like that

Comment: currently I prefix people-{slug}, order-{slug} so it can still be on a single path.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally move both your `/people/123` and `/order/123/` under the same `/123` path. But then, how will you handle the differences? Because an `order` is probably not 95% similar to a `people` in your backend.

Also, even if you can, should you? Probably not.
If you want to keep it clean, follow the conventions and have something fast with less errors, just stay like you are as of right now.

---

If you totally **assume** the aesthetics over the logic of your app, you can have this kind of structure and move your 2 `_id.vue` logic into a single one like this

```
pages/
--| people/
-----| index.vue
--| order/
-----| index.vue
--| _id.vue    !-- you'll need to make it work with both the People and Order model
```